# How to create material cards on button click?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to create mat-cards when clicking on a button.

This is the information, which should be in the mat-card (this information comes from a service).

```
blockHash: "iejg5gpylg6l9gjxor3bnvigs0ipaonr"

blockNumber: 1

previousBlock: "00000000000000000000000000000000"

transactions: Array (1)
0 {sender: "10", recipient: null, amount: null, fee: null}
```

At the beginning the section, where the mat cards are at should be completely empty. When clicking on a button, that section should be filled with one mat-card; when clicking again, a second mat-card should appear and so on.

This is the block with the information (in another component), which gets send to the component, which should add up the material cards.

[image]

This is how it should look like (This is just hardcoded at the moment).

[image]

What's an elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a `parent-component` that displays multiple `card-components`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zvjblo

### parent-component

The `parent-component` holds your list of blocks and displays multiple `card-components` by supplying each `card-component` with the block data for that card. There is also a button to add a new block to the list.

#### template

```html
<button (click)="addCard()">Add Card</button>
<app-block-card *ngFor="let block of blocks" [blockData]="block"></app-block-card>
```

#### code

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BlockData } from './block-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  blocks: BlockData[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.blocks = [];
  }

  addCard() {
    this.blocks.push({
      blockHash: '9348534985720587',
      blockNumber: 3,
      previousBlock: "0000",
      transactions: [
        {
          sender: 'sender',
          recipient: 'recipient',
          amount: 1,
          fee: 200
        }
      ]
    });
  }

}
```

### card-component

The `card-component` receives the data of one block from the parent component and displays it.

#### template

```html
<mat-card class="card">
  <p>{{blockData.blockHash}}</p>
  <p>{{blockData.blockNumber}}</p>
  <p>{{blockData.previousBlock}}</p>
  <p>{{blockData.transactions | json}}</p>
</mat-card>
```

#### code

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BlockData } from '../block-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-block-card',
  templateUrl: './block-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./block-card.component.css']
})
export class BlockCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() blockData: BlockData;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: This works fine! Thank you. But how do I align the cards horizontally?

Comment: @Michael wrap them in a `div` with the style `display: flex;`

Comment: @Michael I updated my stackblitz to a horizontal layout.

Answer (score 0):

You could be using a list, but I am not sure how to make it horizontal so that might require some tweaking.

But, I would say a [drag and drop list](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview)  would also be very fitting.
The documentation easily describes how to apply these with a horizontal view. But if the drag and drop feature is not for you, then the go with the list.

Using either you can run a *ngFor loop that can be performed upon arrays of data.

Example of such:

```
    <div cdkDropList cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" class="example-list" 
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
      <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let card of cardArray" cdkDrag>
        <mat-card class="example-card">
          <mat-card-header>
            <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
            <mat-card-title>Shiba Inu</mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-subtitle>Dog Breed</mat-card-subtitle>
          </mat-card-header>
          <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
          <mat-card-content>
            <p>
             text
            </p>
          </mat-card-content>
          <mat-card-actions>
            <button mat-button>LIKE</button>
            <button mat-button>SHARE</button>
          </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>
      </div>
    </div>
```

In your case you will have to apply the card template inside the *ngFor div, and bind the data accordingly to your naming.

To add a new cards through a button you will simply have to add a new element to the array that you loop over, and it will appear when it has been added.